# unable to edit data on container coming fron a store in Sencha Touch Architect

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Architect 2.1

I have an Store and a Container, but how can I render the data from the store using the container?

I created a 1 minute video explaining the problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HpR9h80D94

In other words this is what I want to do in Secha Designer 2:

```
data: ordersStoreId.getData(),
```

Compleate:

```
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'MyContainer6',
            iconCls: 'info',
            data: ordersStoreId.getData(),
            tpl: [
                'Testing: {status}'
            ]
```

Any idea? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this looks like a bug. I guess one way to work around this issue is to add the `show` listener to your container and then you can dynamically pull in data from your `store`.

```
listeners: {
    show: function(this, opts){
        this.setData( Ext.getStore('yourStore').getData() );
    }
}
```

So in Architect:

1) Select your container

2) In your config window add an `Event Bindings` by clicking the `+` icon and choose `Basic Event Binding`

3) Choose the event name `show` like I suggested. You will then be presented with an editable code view where you can put your code. ex:

```
this.setData( Ext.getStore('yourStore').getData() );
```

Hope this helps.